# Erro ao clicar no primeiro botão de uma Dialog

Tags: android, testes

Pessoal estou tentando fazer o click para confirmar minha ação em um test instrumentado, porém estou com um problema que não encontrei saída ainda alguém consegue me ajudar? estou tentando o seguinte:

```
fun clickPositiveButton(title: String) {
    checkIsDialogDisplayed(title)
    onView(withId(android.R.id.button1)).perform(click())
}

fun checkIsDialogDisplayed(title: String) {
    onView(withText(title))
        .inRoot(isDialog())
       .check(matches(isDisplayed()))
}
```

Tentando fazer esse click estou recebendo este erro:

`androidx.test.espresso.PerformException: Error performing 'single click - At Coordinates: 894, 1004 and precision: 16, 16' on view 'with id: android:id/button1'.`